# Jenkins Groovy script to update mail body line to bold

Tags: html, css, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In below script in mail body, I want Triggered line to come in bold, I added a tag for bold but doesn't work, in mail it comes as simple Triggered PdeInterop

```
// Sending email with the log content and pipeline status
def emailSubject = (system_os == 'Windows') ? "Windows Pipeline Execution: $pipelineStatus" : "Linux Pipeline Execution: $pipelineStatus"

def emailBody = "Rebuilds build #${currentBuild.number}\n"
emailBody += "<pre>[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline\n"
emailBody += "[Pipeline] node\n"
emailBody += "Running on Jenkins in ${env.WORKSPACE}\n"
emailBody += "[Pipeline] {\n\n" // Add OS information to the email body

// Print log content for debugging
println("Log Content:")
println(logContent)
println("updatedLogContent:")
println(updatedLogContent)


// Split log content by lines
def logLines = updatedLogContent.split('\n')

// Iterate through log content to color code pipeline status and process URL lines separately
for (def i = 0; i < logLines.size(); i++) {
    def line = logLines[i]
    if (line.startsWith(" Triggered")) {
        emailBody += "<font face='Calibri (Body)' color='blue'><b>$line</b></font>\n" // Make the "Triggered" line bold
    } else if (line.startsWith(" Job URL")) {
        emailBody += "<font face='Calibri (Body)' color='blue'>$line</font>\n" // Color the "Job URL" line
        // Check if the next line contains "Goto URL"
        if (i + 1 < logLines.size() && logLines[i + 1].startsWith(" Goto URL")) {
            emailBody += "<font face='Calibri (Body)' color='blue'>" + logLines[i + 1] + "</font>\n" // Include "Goto URL"
            i++ // Move to the next line
        }
    } else if (line.startsWith(" Stage")) {
        def status = line.tokenize()[3] // Extracting the status
        switch(status) {
            case "successfully.":
                emailBody += "<font face='Calibri (Body)' color='green'>$line</font>\n"
                break
            case "UNSTABLE":
                emailBody += "<font face='Calibri (Body)' color='yellow'>$line</font>\n"
                break
            default:
                emailBody += "<font face='Calibri (Body)' color='red'>$line</font>\n"
        }
    } else {
        emailBody += "<font face='Calibri (Body)'>$line</font>\n"
    }
}

emailBody += "\n[Pipeline] //}</pre>\n" // Add pipeline end
emailext body: emailBody, subject: emailSubject, to: "avinash.akotkar@keysight.com", mimeType: 'text/html'

// Set pipeline result
currentBuild.result = pipelineStatus
```

Comment: Strictly the b tag no longer means bold see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b Have you tried inline-CSS instead? And maybe you could cut down the code in the question to the bare essentials. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried the default `mail` step instead of `emailext`? I don't remember the details but AFAIR the only (although arguable IMO) advantage of `emailext` is an ability to use the admin-defined templates uploaded to the Jenkins controller. Also, I wouldn't call sending all the logs as email and parsing them line by line a good approach - logs can be hundreds of MBs is size, and Jenkins has built-in methods to extract the build/stage status and check if some line exists in a log.